# When I try to debug a script for indesign in ExtendScriptTK I get the app.documents as undefined, if I run the script from indesign it works

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I don't know why nobody got this issue, but in indesign cs6 when I try to debug it is not attached to the current opened document, how I might do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Choose InDesign from the top left "target" dropdown in your ESTK source window, it probably targets ExtendScript itself.

To automatically achieve the same effect, use the following as first line in your script:

```
#target "indesign"
```